# Bug tracking by debugging when a variable changes

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm a beginner at programming and having a very difficult time tracking down bugs, this happens because usually place a variable on watch, and keep pressing f5 until i notice some change. I'm on visual c# 2010 and i have 18000 lines of code, so only with some luck i do get to catch the problem.

Is there a way to instantly go to the line of code when a variable changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your variable into a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) and put a breakpoint on the setter.  Then you can have a single breakpoint that will hit each time a piece of code changes its value.

So if you have:

```
int myVariable;
```

Change it to:

```
int myVariable {
   get;
   set; // <-- Put your breakpoint here
}
```

Comment: that's pretty complex for me, can you make your answer more acessible?

Comment: @ng80092a  I'm not sure what's so complex about a property.  I've added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a design problem. Ideally, you should limit the places where a variable changes to very specific locations in your code. This is one reason to avoid global variables and static variables unless you have very good reasons to use them. Even then, you should define accessor methods as an interface for these variables rather than changing them directly.

As you debug your code, I suggest you look for ways you can improve it so that debugging isn't so difficult in the future.

Comment: Yes, i'm learning not to spam code the hard way :( I've solved all the issues so far anyways :)

Comment: what design values should i use? i looked for it on google, but there's nothing specific about it

Comment: @ng80092a Object Oriented Design is a huge topic that cannot be easily covered in a single blog or Q&A. There is certainly a lot of information out there about this topic, including many print books.

Answer (score 1):

You can have conditional breakpoints, that will only be hit when a condition is met.

So, assuming you have an index variable `indx`, you can put a conditinal break point, saying *only stop when value = 7*, and then it'll stop there when you're condition changes...

Have a look at this [msdn page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/03/set-a-simple-breakpoint-condition-vstipdebug0021.aspx)
and at this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDabuT-JDXE) tutorial.

Comment: however this method would require me to insert a breakpoint in everyline

Comment: like other answers said, sounds like your issues are running a bit deeper then, design wise.

Answer (score 1):

In native code, your best bet would be to setup a data breakpoint. A data breakpoint fires when the data changes, irrespective of where the change comes from.

You can't do this for .NET however. You can't ask the debugger to break when the value of a variable changes. But, not all hope is lost. Do a "Find Usages" or "Find References" on the variable in question to find all places in your code that make use of the variable. Then set a breakpoint at each of those locations to see when the value of the variable changes.